# Binded jar leaves launcher icon

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

I have an App that uses a some Services from a binded Jar.

But this Jar leaves it own launcher Icon when I deploy this App on a Device. (So I have two launcher Icons)

Here is the Manifest File from this Jar project. What do I have to remove/do to make my Application leaves only the one desired launch Icon. (Only from MainApp)

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.scandemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ScanDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.company.scandemo.FloatingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.company.scandemo.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I have to remove/do to make my Application leaves only the one desired launch Icon

Please delete the `MainLauncher` flag from the manifest file in your binded Jar:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>

  //Delete these flag
```